# How to combine charts in Tableau

Tags: charts, tableau-api, cjk

[image]

Every column have same 6 level of factor variables.(5 columns)

These charts are count of record by levels.

How do i combine these charts into one?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put the predefined field **Measure** **Values** on the Row Shelf. The you’ll see a new shelf appear called Measure Values. Place the measures you want to see on the Measure Values shelf (and remove them from the Rows shelf)

Then place the predefined field **Measure** **Names** on The color or label shelf.

Comment: Thanks. I succeeded in including several Measure Values in one chart. But i dont know how to change the x-axis of a chart. These 5 columns have factors with the same levels(1,2,3,4,5,6). I want to express by factor levels, not by column names.

Comment: Don’t put Measure Names on the Column Shelf; only on Color. Instead put the field you had all by itself on rows in the original example onto the columns shelf. (you can later swap row and column if you like to transpose the view) Also make sure you have the right aggregation function - Are you sure you want CNT() instead of MEDIAN() for example. If the function you want is not available, check to make sure the field has the right data type.